# Google Mock Class Constructor with parameters depending on other objects

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googlemock

```
  class MockBaseClass : public BaseClass
  {

    public:
    // Constructor
    MockBaseClass(MockDep1 * pA)
     :BaseClass( pA)
    {
       mpA = pA;
    }
```

MockDep1 is a mock for Dep1

BaseClass

`BaseClass(Dep1 *pA)`
`{`
`..`...
`mpX = new X(pA->getCollection()->getA());//crashes`
`}`

How can I avoid this situation? I tried to make a mock for X class but I don't know how to use it because the constructor of the Base Class is called anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by mocking the methods from MockDep1